# I can no longer boot into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, ubuntu-gnome, recovery-mode

I'm really new to Ubuntu and got my PC about 2 months ago. While I was crypto mining I tried to figure out how to overclock using GreenwithEnvy but it kept giving me the error: "Error Applying Overclocks!" So I tried to fix that error using multiple suggestions from Google but to no avail. At that time my PC was running smoothly and I had to go to my Cousin's house. And to leave my PC running for crypto mining I put it down on lock screen. Unfortunately when I came back, I tried to go on Google to show my Dad my Ethermine dashboard but everything was so damn slow. My dad thought it was the connection and took out my Antenna for my WIFI. While he was doing that the PC abruptly turned off for no reason(my motherboard is an B550 Aorus Elite AX V.2 with bios version 16a). We thought that I didn't plug in the cords correctly but when double checking the wires on my PC, everything was plugged into the right place perfectly pushed in tight. I tried going to recovery mode to clean it out and remove a cool bits option I added but I still ended up on the same screen whenever I try to boot up Ubuntu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xq0n.jpg)

If the image doesn't show up, then here's what the screen states: "/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 366060/61022208 files, 10885821/244059136 blocks"

Please help, I don't understand anything that's going on(I don't know anything about code and I'm 15). If u need any information from me be free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

My advice - stop mining, learn a bit about computers - it'll serve you much better in the long term. You'll make a lot more money if you learn how to code, learn how a computer works, and get a steady job rather than trying to mine cryptocurrency on a home computer. If it was that easy we'd all be rich.